# SQL combine 3 rows to 1 with other values combined to string

Tags: mysql, sql, export

Hey I have trouble combining 3 rows with same number but different values.

I have a `table` that looks like this:

| artikelnummer | kategorie |
| --- | --- |
| 34462 | 264 |
| 34462 | 460 |
| 34462 | 331 |

And I want to create a SQL Statement for a `CSV` Export that looks like this:

| artikelnummer | kategorie |
| --- | --- |
| 34462 | "264|460|331" |

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database.

Comment: Ive added the Tag

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function is used to add double quotes in the beginning and in the end.

`Group_concat` is used to CONCAT values, it is like grouping values, the default SEPARATOR is `,` used the SEPARATOR property and set it to `|`

```
SELECT artikelnummer,
       Concat('"', Group_concat(kategorie SEPARATOR '|'), '"') kategorie
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY artikelnummer;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.
I didnt knew about that feature, since i havent done much SQL. (At least not in a kinda complex manner)
I gotta look into that more

Answer (score 0):

usage:

```
   SELECT artikelnummer ,GROUP_CONCAT(kategorie)
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY artikelnummer ;
```